# Alerts for Website status and Mail's from grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus, alerts

I am new to grafana and prometheus.

I have a use-case like to send mail when respective status happen:

for status 500 - mail to "X-person" saying website is having 500 error.

for status 404 - mail to "Y-person" saying website is having 404 error.

for status 200 - Mail to "Z-person" saying website is back online.

Can we do these in grafana, based on a single graph?

And I have created a table in grafana to show all the needed data from black_box exporter and prometheus. But I couldn't find an alert config in grafana for the same. Is there a way to do it?

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier to do it with alertmanage which is nice tool to root alerts from prometheus to specific alerting channels. But it's also possible with grafana. If you want more help, please provide some more info about metrics which you use.

Comment: I have to build a Monitoring and Alerting setup for a cluster of  servers. So i started with building the setup using Prometheus, Node Exporter, Blackbox Exporter and grafana. Now i am very confused to either use Alert manager of prometheus or Grafana alerting for all the alerting scenarios.

Alerting temple i need to follow is 3 kinds of rules  1. Ok 2. Warning 3. Critical. 

so lets say if i have cpu utilization till 50% its in OK state, 51% to 70% its Warning, 71% and more its critical.

can we do this setup with both, or which is convenient.

Answer (score 0):

I have to build a Monitoring and Alerting setup for a cluster of servers. So i started with building the setup using Prometheus, Node Exporter, Blackbox Exporter and grafana.

Now i am very confused to either use Alert manager of prometheus or Grafana alerting for all the alerting scenarios.

Alerting temple i need to follow is 3 kinds of rules:
1. Ok 
2. Warning 
3. Critical.

so lets say if i have cpu utilization till 50% its in OK state, 51% to 70% its Warning, 71% and more its critical.

Can we do this setup with both, or which is convenient.